# MySQL insert with sub select slow

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

We are using Python and LOAD DATA INFILE to load data from CSVs into our staging database. From staging we have sql scripts moving the data into our actual production database.

LOAD DATA INFILE is lightning fast compared to selecting rows from staging and inserting them into production.

We are on 5.7, using InnoDB and we have applied the following configuration to optimise our inserts:

- Set innodb_autoinc_lock_mode to 2
- Set innodb buffer pool size to half of the memory (16GB)
- Set log buffer size to 4GB
- We are using TRANSACTIONS
- Use SET autocommit=0;

Still the insert from one table to another is significantly slower compared to LOAD DATA INFILE.

When I look at IO writes, with load data infile it goes up to 30 MB/s, while with normal inserts, it's max 500KB/sec.

Is there any way we could improve this performance or do we need to completely rethink our approach. I can think of using OUTFILE for sub queries and load that back in with INFILE but it doesn't sound like the right approach.

And the statement:

```
INSERT INTO documentkey (documentClassCode,dId,fileTypeCode,internet,pathId,creationTime,signature,CSVimportId) 
SELECT case when csv.`Document Class` is null
                then (select classCode from mydb.class where classDesc = 'Empty'
                    And LookupId = (select LookupId from mydb.Lookup where LookupGroupCode = 'C' and EntityLookedup = 'documentkey')
                    )
                else (select classCode from mydb.class where    classDesc = csv.`Document Class`
                    And LookupId = (select LookupId from mydb.Lookup where LookupGroupCode = 'C' and EntityLookedup = 'documentkey')
                    )
        end,
        csv.`dId`,
        (select typeCode from mydb.type
                Where typeDesc = csv.`File Type`
                And LookupId = (select LookupId from mydb.Lookup where LookupGroupCode = 'T' and EntityLookedup = 'documentkey')
        ),
        case    when csv.`message ID` is null
                then (select messageIncrId from message where internetdesc = 'Empty')
                else case   when    exists (select internetMessageIncrId from internetMessage where internetdesc = csv.`Internet Message ID`)
                            then    (select internetMessageIncrId from internetMessage where internetdesc = csv.`Internet Message ID`)
                            else    0
                    end
        end,
        case    when exists (select pathId from Path where pathDesc = csv.`path`)
                then    (select pathId from Path where pathDesc = csv.`path`)
                else 0
        end,
        case when csv.`Creation Time` <> '' then STR_TO_DATE(csv.`Creation Time`, '%d/%m/%Y  %H:%i:%s') else '2016-06-16 10:00:00' end,
        #STR_TO_DATE(csv.`Creation Time`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),
        csv.`Signature Hash`,
        1
        #csv.`CSV import id`
FROM `mydb_stage`.`csvDocumentKey` csv
where csv.`dId` is not null and csv.threadId = @thread;
```

Select part of the query only takes a fraction of a second.

Explain:

```
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'csv', NULL, 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '1', '100.00', 'Using where'
'12', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'path', NULL, 'eq_ref', 'pathDesc_UNIQUE', 'pathDesc_UNIQUE', '1026', 'func', '1', '100.00', 'Using where; Using index'
'11', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'path', NULL, 'eq_ref', 'pathDesc_UNIQUE', 'pathDesc_UNIQUE', '1026', 'func', '1', '100.00', 'Using where; Using index'
'10', 'SUBQUERY', 'message', NULL, 'const', 'messageDesc_UNIQUE', 'messageDesc_UNIQUE', '2050', 'const', '1', '100.00', 'Using index'
'9', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'message', NULL, 'eq_ref', 'messageDesc_UNIQUE', 'messageDesc_UNIQUE', '2050', 'func', '1', '100.00', 'Using where; Using index'
'8', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'message', NULL, 'eq_ref', 'messageDesc_UNIQUE', 'messageDesc_UNIQUE', '2050', 'func', '1', '100.00', 'Using where; Using index'
'6', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'type', NULL, 'eq_ref', 'typeDesc_UNIQUE', 'typeDesc_UNIQUE', '1026', 'func', '1', '100.00', 'Using index condition; Using where'
'7', 'SUBQUERY', 'Lookup', NULL, 'ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '6', 'const', '3', '10.00', 'Using where'
'4', 'SUBQUERY', 'class', NULL, 'const', 'classDesc_UNIQUE', 'classDesc_UNIQUE', '1026', 'const', '1', '100.00', NULL
'5', 'SUBQUERY', 'Lookup', NULL, 'ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '6', 'const', '2', '10.00', 'Using where'
'2', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'class', NULL, 'eq_ref', 'classDesc_UNIQUE', 'classDesc_UNIQUE', '1026', 'func', '1', '20.00', 'Using index condition; Using where'
'3', 'SUBQUERY', 'Lookup', NULL, 'ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '6', 'const', '2', '10.00', 'Using where'
```

Comment: One reason `LOAD DATA` is fast is because it isn't really doing any database stuff, whereas the `INSERT` is.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I assume it is running with certain config settings that are transparent for the user, and I would imagine you could achieve similar configuration and hence performance for INSERTs. It's just a question of how.

Comment: How do you select and insert the data. can you show us the query

Comment: @BerndBuffen I've added the statement

Comment: @L4zl0w - Thanks, can please show us the explain of the SELECT Statement (without INSERT...): EXPLAIN SELECT case when csv.`Document Class` is null
                then (select classCode from mydb.class where classDesc = 'Empty'
 ....... ; it looks like that your query to select the data from table is very slow

Comment: @BerndBuffen I can't at the moment because I have connectivity issues, I will as soon as I can but as I said the SELECT part of the query was very quick, we have the indexes on those tables.

Comment: Where's this transaction that you're talking about? Your code sure doesn't use it. *How* are you using transactions?

Comment: There is START TRANSACTION before this statement and COMMIT; after. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: How many rows in that `SELECT`?

Comment: Tack on `ORDER BY the-primary-key-of-documentkey`.  See if that speeds it up.

Answer (score 1):

You do not mention why you want to change your approach especially if performance is you primary target.
SELECT can *not* be as fast as dumping a file in a table and that is already stated explicitly in the MySQL docs
From [insert-speed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-speed.html)

> When loading a table from a text file, use LOAD DATA INFILE. This is
>   usually 20 times faster than using INSERT statements. See Section
>   14.2.6, “LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax”.

Comment: thanks, we need to load in 1 billion records in less than 12 hours into staging and from there into production. Now getting the records into staging is not a problem, but from staging to production it is taking very long. What I don't understand is why an INSERT from select is slow, if your SELECT statement is fast. I would imagine that the result of the select statement is in the memory, from where it should be fast to insert. But I'm clearly missing something because this is not what I'm experiencing.

Comment: `INSERT` is slow because MySQL is ACID compliant and uses 1 I/O of your disk to perform the insert. Grouping inserts in a transactions lets your disk use 1 I/O but utilize much more bandwith. LOAD DATA INFILE is avoiding the SQL layer and uses disk efficiently. The reason you're experiencing slowness is because of your hard drive. Get sold state drives for your db server(s), and pay attention to their IOPS count. You won't solve anything by writing optimal code - this is related to hardware as well, you can go only so far with code alone.

Comment: I understand but this statement is significantly slower than other, more simple insert statements. I'm talking ~20 times slower. There is only 150-400KB write on disk with this statement. That is not IO bottleneck.

Comment: @L4zl0w: `INSERT INTO FROM SELECT` is a transaction. Hence many things must be done besides dumping data into the table.

Comment: How scattered are the rows you are inserting?  It could be that the blocks to insert _into_ are scattered, and _reads_ from disk are the bottleneck.